# PHP - function that both returns and echoes a value

Tags: php

I would like to **create a function** that **both returns and echoes a value**.
But **not** the two together. **Or** return **or** echo.
And I am looking for a beautiful way to do it.
Almost all functions / class methods in my project must have this option.

I can pass to a function a bool value that indicates whether to echo or to return a value but it seems not so beautiful to me.

How, you think, it is better to implement this? Maybe a built-in option in PHP?

Comment: You can use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) & friends, but that is certainly uglier than passing a boolean...

Comment: What's wrong with `echo alwaysreturn()`. A Boolean go avoid typing echo is hardly useful.

Comment: I am developing an API and using a framework. Routes in my project are directly mapped to class methods. And this methods echoes JSON responses. What I want to achieve is to use the class methods, if needed, in other parts of the project. That means I do not want the value to be printed, I need it returned.

Comment: That does not sound like a good design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a boolean value is a good way to go, [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) does the same:

> **mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )**
>
> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return
>   parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return
>   the information rather than print it.